# Making an index for a R package documentation

Tags: r, documentation

I developed a R package available through the CRAN repository. But because the number of functions begins to be quite large, I want to introduce an html index to find most rapidly the chosen function in the RStudio "help" view as it is made for many packages.

I'm expecting something like that:
[image]

But I don't find how to proceed.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: R will automatically generate the index page from your package metadata as long as you've included the appropriate documentation or all your functions. You cannot supply your own index as an HTML page. You cannot customize the default representation. Are you currently build the Rd help pages? Are you using a package like `roxygen` to build documentation?

Comment: Yes, I built the help pages using roxygen. However I want to improve the help presentation introducing an index (A B C etc.) above the function list, which allows to access more rapidly to the function beginning with A, B, C, etc. As it is done with the lubridate package illustrated above.

Comment: That is not something you can control. That is automatically included once the total number of documented functions reaches a certain threshold. I forget what the actual number is, but if you don’t see those links for your package you must be under the threshold.